# Python code to read from a file and finding count of a word

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures

This is the problem statement

Write a program to read through the mbox-short.txt and figure out who has the sent the greatest number of mail messages. The program looks for 'From ' lines and takes the second word of those lines as the person who sent the mail. The program creates a Python dictionary that maps the sender's mail address to a count of the number of times they appear in the file. After the dictionary is produced, the program reads through the dictionary using a maximum loop to find the most prolific committer.

```
name = input("Enter file:")
if len(name) < 1 : 
    name = "mbox-short.txt"
handle = open(name)
a=dict()
for line in handle:
    if line.startswith('From'):
        line=line.rstrip()
        words=line.split()
        for word in words:
            a[word]=a.get(name,0)+1
            print(a)
```

This is the code i have written. I know this is incomplete as i am not able to figure out the logic to do this. Please help. The desired output is cwen@iupui.edu 5 
where cwen@iupui.edu is the word which appears the most and 5 is the count. So, it means cwem@iupui.edu appears 5 times in the text file. Remember every sender email ID starts after the first word (S0 first word is from and the second word is the sender ID (all differetn with differetn domain)). So, i need the maximum count of the most appearing sender ID. Hope this helps. Please let me know if you all want more details. And please help as i am stuck on this.

Comment: Could you post a minimal input file with the correct format?

Comment: Instead of counting words. You have solve this problem with regex. Provide some sample input so that we can help you to solve problem.

Comment: it should be `a[word] = a.get[word], 0) + 1`. Name is your filename, it should _not_ be present in the file.